# Java - instantiating objects of same class in its constructor

Tags: java, constructor, stack-overflow

Why instantiating objects of same class within its constructor throws `StackOverflowError`?
For instance ,

```
public class A {
    public A () {
        A a = new A() 
    }
}
```

will throw `StackOverFlowError` ?

Comment: A fine example of infinite recursion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's exactly the same as with any other function unconditionally calling itself with exactly the same parameters:

```
public void f() {
  f(); // <---- will cause a stack overflow due to infinite recursion
}
```

The function just keeps calling itself, and each invocation requires stack space. Sooner or later the stack is exhausted, and you get an exception.

Exactly the same thing happens when `A()` keeps calling itself (in `new A()`).

Answer (score 5):

Because your `new A()` statement will call the constructor of the `A` class, which will call the constructor of the `A` class, and so on. This creates an infinite recursion. THis causes the JVM to throw `StackOverflowError`s.